# TS2344: generic extends string literal type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a class that has a generic string literal type that extends some other (narrower) string literal type. I tried this:

```
type TypeA = 'First' | 'Second';
type TypeB = TypeA | 'Third';
type TypeC = 'Fourth';

class ClassA<T extends TypeA = TypeA> {
  prop?: T;
}

const a: ClassA = {};
const b: ClassA<TypeB> = {}; // <- don't want error
const c: ClassA<TypeC> = {}; // <- should throw error
```

but I got this error for the `const b`:

```
TS2344: Type  TypeB  does not satisfy the constraint  TypeA 
Type  "Third"  is not assignable to type  TypeA
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oHIBiBLATgZ2DSgB90BlCAYwHsA7AEzQG4AoUSWeAIRU8iVJoYAC1yNWLSgBsAhnjxQAwrPkIAPDCgQAHsAgMFcfryOIAfFADeLKFDA5qYAPwAuWKwC+LSXQJQZbspyeEiolh6sNLR+AEaBKiEa3BZhEUA)

My goal is to allow `ClassA` to take a wider string literal type than `TypeA` like `TypeB`, but `TypeC` should throw some error.

Comment: How about `T extends string = TypeA`?

Comment: Yes works, but the restriction for T is loss. I'm looking for something that has that limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *extend* a union, you (optionally) *reduce* its membership. For instance, `"First"` is a valid extension of `TypeA`, because it's a subset of `TypeA`'s members. You can't go the other direction via `extends`. This is in contrast to extending a structure, where you can add additional properties but can't remove them. It seems odd at first, but it makes sense: When `C extends B`, it means that `C` must be assignable to `B`. For a structure, that means `C` must have all of `B`'s properties (and can have additional ones); for a union, that means `C` must be a union of `B`'s members (or a subset of them) so that any member of `C` can be assigned to a `B` value. In both cases, assignment is valid because `C` *is a* `B`.

I think the closest you can get here is to use `T extends string = TypeA`, which sadly doesn't include the restriction you wanted (that the union contain `"First"` and `"Second"`):

```typescript
type TypeA = "First" | "Second";
type TypeB = TypeA | "Third";

class ClassA<T extends string = TypeA> {
    prop?: T;
}

const a: ClassA = {};
const b: ClassA<TypeB> = {};

b.prop
// ^? −−− (property) ClassA<TypeB>.prop?: TypeB | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oCIBiBLATgZ2DSgB90BlCAYwHsA7AEzQG4AoUSWeAIRU8iVJoYAC1yNWLSgBsAhnjxQAwrPkIAPDCgQAHsAgMFBHFloBzXnH4A+KAG8WUR1DA5qYAPwAuWKwC+LSToCKBlvZTk8JFRbX1YaWmCAIzCVSI1uG2jYgMSAOhc3FgB6IqgAPXcgA)

Another option for you would be to make the type of `prop` `TypeA | T`, so that `prop` would always include the `TypeA` options and the generic type parameter would add to them:

```typescript
type TypeA = "First" | "Second";
type TypeB = TypeA | "Third";

class ClassA<T extends string = TypeA> {
    prop?: TypeA | T;
}

const a: ClassA = {};
const b: ClassA<TypeB> = {};
const c: ClassA<"Fourth"> = {}; // <== Works because the generic argument *adds to* `TypeA`
c.prop
// ^? −−− (property) ClassA<"Fourth">.prop?: TypeA | "Fourth" | undefined

b.prop
// ^? −−− (property) ClassA<TypeB>.prop?: "First" | "Second" | "Third" | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oCIBiBLATgZ2DSgB90BlCAYwHsA7AEzQG4AoUSWeAIRU8iVJoYAC1yNWLSgBsAhnjxQAwrPkIAPDCgQAHsAgMFBHFloBzXnH4A+KAG8WUR1DA5qYAPwAuPohKxWAL4sknQEUDLeynJ4SKi2Aaw0tGEARpEqMRrcNnEJIcnAUJTp0eqY1ACuOMDCaDl2CVAA9E1QasioAOrUOADWCilUMhV40DXQpvoQxpThOKYVALb6hQBUMvT0CsDUq1AABpaI+5IAdC5uLC1QAHruwSnnrmBXrXdAA)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know that I can replace 'extends TypeA' to 'extends string' and it works, but I'm looking for sth that includes this restriction (don't know if even possible :) ).

Comment: @A.Radej - I don't think you can go that way via `extends`. I've added a second option for you that may be closer to what you want, but I *think* you can't get exactly what you want. (I could be wrong, though. It's hard to prove a negative -- doubly so in TypeScript, in my experience. :-) )

Comment: Okay, thank you for really helpful response. I misunderstood the extends meaning for unions.

Comment: @A.Radej - That's very easy to do. :-)